# Hiding UI element from fragment.xml in standard App

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I want to hide few UI elements from My Travel and Expense (Standard App). I have tried in different approaches but I am not able to achieve what i want. Here is my requirement:

In My Travel and Expense App (TRV_TE_CRE), I want to hide the following UI elements:

`GenericClaim.fragment.xml - Button id="costAssignmentButton"`

I have added the extension project for TRV_TE_CRE and tried as below:

1. In `component.js` I added the following statement to hide
   customizing:

   ```
   {
       "sap.ui.viewModifications": {
       "mytravelandexpense.view.GenericClaim": {
           "costAssignmentButton": {
               "visible": false
           },
       },
   },
   ```

   Result: not working
2. Extended the `GenericClaim.controller.js`:
   I added the below code in hookmethod

   ```
   this.byFragmentId("costAssignmentButton").setVisible(false);
   ```

   Result : whole claim page is not loading
3. By using access key I have commented the UI code in `GenericClaim.fragment.xml`

   Result : not getting hide

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the fragment ID, you can access the element ID from the view. Add this method in your view controller.

```
onAfterRendering : function(){
    var buttonToHide = this.getView().byId("costAssignmentButton");
    buttonToHide.setVisible(false);
},
```

Comment: U mean I have to try inside onAfterRendering() from extended project of standard app. Because inside onAfterRendering there is no hookmethod for extending and one more thing I have tried as below in hookmethod, this.getView().byId("costAssignmentButton").setVisible(false). result: whole page is not loading

Comment: Which hook method did you try? onAfterRendering is a hook method that is called after view is created. Add that method to the controller file of your view if it is not already there.